# Como controlar un fetch dentro de un map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

bendiciones para todos. Hice un fetch dentro de un useEffect para consumir los nombres de los primeros 5 pokemones en un map(sin problemas), dentro de la data del fetch hay otra url para consumir la imagen de los pokemones, el problema es que al hacer el otro fecth para consumir no logro controlar las url's de las imagenes y se renderean como quieren y no como yo deseo, necesito que por favor me ayuden. Este es el codigo:

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch(url)
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(data => {
    setPokelist(data)
    setNext(data.next)
    setPrevious(data.previous)
})}, [url])


useEffect(() => { {/*Aqui estan los problemas*/}
    pokelist.results &&
    pokelist.results.map((pokemon) => {
        fetch(pokemon.url)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            setUrlImg(data.sprites.front_default)
        })
    })
}, [pokelist])
```

Esto es lo que retorna:

```
return (
<>
<div className='pokelist'>
    <h1>PokeList</h1>
    </div>
{
    pokelist.results &&
    pokelist.results.map((pokemon) => {
        return (
        <div key={pokemon.name} className='poke'>
        <h2>{pokemon.name}</h2>
        <img className='imagen' src={urlImg}{*/No controlo esto/*} alt={pokemon.name} />
    </div>     
        )

    })    
}
{previous ? <button onClick={handleAnterior} >Anterior</button> : <button disabled>Anterior</button> }
<button onClick={handleSiguiente} >Siguiente</button>
</> )}
```

Perdonen si me extendi demasiado, es mi primera vez en la comunidad. Muchas gracias de Antemano.

Comment: No veo necesario hacer un `fetch` para obtener la imagen. La `url` de la imagen será usada en el componente de imagen, ¿para qué querrías hacer una segunda llamada?

Comment: Eso me lo dejaron como tarea, ya que al hacer el primer fetch, lo que obtengo de la data aparte del nombre es otra url, que debo fetchear para obtener la url de la imagen, es decir la url de la imagen no me aparece en el primer fetch, lo que me aparece es una url la cual es un objeto que contiene entre otras cosas, la url de la imagen.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir la URL que consumes, y un ejemplo del resultado que obtienes de esa primera consulta?

Comment: No la tengo en este momento, pero, obtengo el nombre del pokemon y otra url, la cual me lleva a la imagen en cuestion; en resumidas cuentas: para acceder a la imagen, debo hacer un primer fetch, y con la url que obtengo, debo hacer otro fetch y en vista de eso ya no puedo controlar como se renderizan la imagenes y o aparecen todas a la vez, o solo aparece la ultima que se carga; un completo desastre.